# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 138-139: illegal encoding

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I seem to have this problem when I try importing my data from access, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. How can I fix this? knowing that this is my chunk of code:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\Users\file.accdb; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    columns = [row.column_name for row in cursor.columns(table= table)]     
    sql = 'Select * from table'
    cursor.execute(sql)                                                             
    data = pandas.DataFrame([tuple(t) for t in cursor.fetchall()])                    
    table = pandas.DataFrame(data)                                              
    table.columns = columns
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a known issue with the Access ODBC driver, described here:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#unicodedecodeerror-when-calling-cursorcolumns

One possible workaround is to use an output converter function as illustrated [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/328#issuecomment-419655266):

```py
def decode_sketchy_utf16(raw_bytes):
    s = raw_bytes.decode("utf-16le", "ignore")
    try:
        n = s.index('\u0000')
        s = s[:n]  # respect null terminator
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s

# …

prev_converter = cnxn.get_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, decode_sketchy_utf16)
col_info = crsr.columns("Clients").fetchall()
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, prev_converter)  # restore previous behaviour
```